# calculate how long ago a file was modified

Tags: unix, date, time

I need a script that calculates how long ago a file was modified. This can be days ago or just minutes ago.
I already was able to get the modification date and time from the stat-command. I stored this data in two different variables.
Now I need to calculate the difference between this date and time with "now".
I can find lots of examples of getting the difference between two dates or time. But what if my time goes back more then a day.
ex. modif date 2013-06-25  23:55:00
    now        2013-06-26  00:10:08
If I calculate the difference between these two I need the answer 15 minutes and 8 seconds.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `stat` give you the times in seconds, then subtract the values. Divide by 60 if you want minutes, use modulo 60 to get the remainder in seconds.

Comment: This is the solution. I was truying to do this in two steps. First get the modification time and date with stat and then I tried to put this date in the format "seconds since ..." There I failed. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Jens answer works, here's an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

MOD_TIME=`stat -c %Y thisfile.txt`
RIGHTNOW=`date +%s`
HOW_LONG=`expr $RIGHTNOW - $MOD_TIME`
NUM_MINS=`expr $HOW_LONG / 60`
NUM_SECS=`expr $HOW_LONG % 60`

echo "$NUM_MINS minutes, $NUM_SECS seconds since modified."
```